# Black with VSCode

Tags: python, html

I'm using "black" for python on VSCODE. It's a very good tool, however I have a rather annoying little problem. It segments my html files and causes bugs...

How to prevent the "black" from intervening on my HTML files?

Comment: By not using black to format html files?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Truly extraordinary. Where is this man's Nobel prize?

Comment: @AlanSTACK what more do you expect when a question has so little detail?

Comment: I would expect black to ruin only on files with `.py` extension. How did you configure it, so that it caused your problem?

Answer (score 2):

In preferences, you need to set your Default Formatter to None.

In your Python preferences you can then set Black as your language-specific formatter.

[image]

P.S: Open preferences by pressing Ctrl + p, open preferences, then search for formatter.